# Unable to see manually created playbooks in AWX

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, ansible-awx

I have a strange issue that has me racking my brain. I have installed AWX 22.3.0 onto Ubuntu 22.04.1-Ubuntu at least 3 times now. Let me make sure I get everything to those reading this.

I have followed many whitepapers, directions, and videos, and for the life of me, I can't figure out why I can't get any playbooks using,.yaml or.yml in the /var/lib/awx/projects/ to show up within "Base Project Path". I continue to receive the message below:

"There are no available playbook directories in /var/lib/awx/projects. Either that directory is empty, or all of the contents are already assigned to other projects. Create a new directory there and make sure the playbook files can be read by the "awx" system user, or have AWX directly retrieve your playbooks from source control using the Source Control Type option above.

I'm using K3S Kubernetes, and my pods are all active and working.

I have edited my "awx-web" to make sure it has the /var/lib/awx/projects path as the

kubectl exec -ti deploy/awx-web -c awx-web -- /bin/bash

env

export PROJECTS_ROOT="/new/path/to/projects"

All of it looks good. I deleted and recreated the pod after the change as well. But the ROOT path was already there originally, as I expected based on how I installed.

Hopefully, that is enough for people to help me with my problem. I'm just at a loss and don't know what else it could be at this point. I mean, do I need to open firewall ports? I just don't know.

Also, the permissions are below after I did a "mkdir -P" and manually created a /var/lib/awx/projects/playbooks directory. Then created a .yml file.

Maybe it could be permission as well; who knows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)